# Clean Up jQuery Code

Tags: jquery

Is there a more concise way to accomplish the same thing here? I'm trying to set the focus to the first empty field, either the email input or password input.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#email_address').val() == '') {
        $('#email_address').focus();
    } else {
        $('#password').focus();
    }
});
```

My HTML form looks like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="email" id="email_address" />
    <input type="password" id="password" />
</form>
```

Comment: Looks pretty concise.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks @dave for the CodeReview suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $email = $('email_address')
  , $field = $email.val() === '' ? $email : $('#password')
  ;
$field.focus();
```

Or filter, although I'm not convinced that's as immediately clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could attempt to target them both elements and use the `filter` function to find the first of those that is empty.

The code below would be an example of this (it checks the length and determines which elements have no content):

```
$('#email_address,#password').filter(function () { return $(this).val().length == 0; })[0].focus()
```

This assumes that you would check to ensure that one of these values was already empty.

**Edit :**

Upon further thought, I suppose you could use the following selector to target the first empty `<input>` element and give it focus :

```
$('input:empty').focus();
```

Comment: You could even reduce it further by eliminating the jQuery dependency when checking the value: `return this.value.length == 0;`...

Comment: Can't use `:empty` on input, won't return expected results. Definition per docs: `Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes).`

Comment: I know that the docs state that, but it certainly seems to work as per this example : http://jsbin.com/weyava/edit?html,output.